# Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder for finitely-generated algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, quaternions

I am reading [these notes](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2022/LectureNotes12.pdf), and am trying to understand the reasoning in the last sentence of Theorem 13.18. The author shows that if $E$ and $E'$ are isogenous elliptic curves, then $\operatorname{End}^0(E')$ is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra of $\operatorname{End}^0(E)$, and vice versa, then concludes htat $\operatorname{End}^0(E') \cong \operatorname{End}^0(E)$. This appears to be an invokation of the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder (CBS) property, which is discussed at length [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold/), but does not hold in all categories (various counterexamples are available around the internet). My question is - **How do we know that the CBS property holds for finitely-generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras?**

Or perhaps we are using something specific about the case of endomorphism algebras of elliptic curves, like the classification that immediately precedes this Theorem?

Comment: it‘s just linear algebra, basically. Those endomorphism algebras are _finite dimensional_ over the rationals, not just finitely generated.

Comment: the fact that the endomorphism rings embed into each other shows that they have the same dimension and hence any of those two embeddings is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: @LukasHeger More abstractly, CBS holds whenever we have a "good notion of dimension" to work with. Which is indeed the case here.

Comment: Oh I see - I was worried about having an isomorphism as vector spaces vs. having an isomorphism as algebras, but because the algebra embeddings are also embeddings as vector spaces, and the vector spaces are finite-dimensional, we know that the embeddings are surjective as maps between sets. But then they are surjective algebra maps, so they are isomorphisms. Thanks for pointing that out!